# What's the difference between the two logic phrases?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I understand how these two differ when transformed into CNF, but I can't understand how they differ when translated from/to Human language.

$$
1.  \exists x[p(x)\to \exists yq(y)]
$$
$$
2. \exists xp(x)\to \exists y q(y)
$$

Can you give me a sentence in English that will relate to each?

Comment: The one on the bottom isn't a statement as the second occurrence of $x$ isn't free. This means that it is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for this. 
My bad. (First time I'm using this syntax and I had a typo). I fixed both now to what I originally meant. Will you take another look?

Comment: When you say a sentence in English, you mean a regular-looking sentence or just a sentence in English? The reason why I ask is that I suspect that any formulation of the statement on top will sound weird. For the second one, something like "If there's a(n animal that is a) panda, there's a(n animal that is a) quoll" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equivalent; the first one [is equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication): 1') $∀xp(x) → ∃yq(y)$.

In order to find a counterexample, we have to find an interpretation where 1') is True and 2) is False.

Consider this arithmetical example for 2): $\exists x (x=0) \to \exists y (y < 0)$. It is clearly False in $\mathbb N$.

Regarding 1') instead, it is: $\forall x (x=0) \to \exists y (y < 0)$, which is $\text {F} \to \text {F}$ and thus is False in $\mathbb N$.

A natural language example (but, IMO, much less "natural") will be with the domain of Humans and with "Blonde" for $p$ and "Immortal" for $q$.

While 2) will be:

> "if there is some Blonde (Human), then there is some Immortal (Human)",

which is a conditional with true antecedent and false consequent, and thus false, we have for 1):

> "there is some Human such that (if she is Blonde, then there is some Immortal (Human))",

which is false, because there is some black-haired human.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What rule did you apply to conclude that "the first one is equivalent to: 1') ∀xp(x)→∃yq(y)"?

Comment: @Niv - see [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication).